# Javac compilation error

Tags: java, javac

I am trying to compile a Java class but I get this error:

```
 TestRunner.java
TestRunner.java:3: error: package org.junit.runner does not exist
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
                       ^
TestRunner.java:4: error: package org.junit.runner does not exist
import org.junit.runner.Result;
                       ^
TestRunner.java:5: error: package org.junit.runner.notification does not exist
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;
                                    ^
TestRunner.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(ApplicationIT.class);
                ^
  symbol:   class Result
  location: class TestRunner
TestRunner.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(ApplicationIT.class);
```

It is unable to resolve any of the import packages and classes.

I'm not sure what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `package org.junit.runner does not exist` should give you a hint. You are missing a required library. Are you using a build tool?

Comment: yes I am using maven. Should I add that as a dependency?

Comment: Yes, and be sure to say `<scope>test</scope>`.

Comment: You seem to be missing the JUnit .jar in your CLASSPATH.  How to "fix" this depends on how you're compiling and running your unit tests.  Are you using an IDE (e.g. Eclipse or Android Studio)?  Or a script (.bat file, shell script, Ant build.xml, Maven pom.xml, etc)?

Comment: I see, thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error, but
Closing android studio,cleaning the build and again rebuilding it solved my error.